# SSIS package run as SQL Server Authentication in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

Can any one please help me to RUN my SSIS package is SQL Server Authentication Becuase it is excuted.

it is My Stored Procedure Calling method for the SSIS package using SQL Server Authentication

```
DECLARE @execution_id BIGINT;
        EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'windowsuser';
        EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution]
            @package_name = @package_name
            , @execution_id = @execution_id OUTPUT
            , @folder_name = @folder_name
            , @project_name = @project_name
            , @use32bitruntime = False
            , @reference_id = NULL
            , @runinscaleout = False;
        
        EXEC  [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value]
            @execution_id
            , @object_type = 30
            , @parameter_name = N'SbInvoiceID'
            , @parameter_value = @SBInvoiceId;
        
        EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id;
        REVERT
```

- The **[catalog].[create_execution]** and **[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value]** is Run succesfully using **EXECUTE AS LOGIN** it but **[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id** throw error.

ERROR :

```
Msg 27123, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The operation cannot be started by an account that uses SQL Server Authentication. Start the operation with an account that uses Integrated Authentication.
Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Procedure internal.start_execution_internal, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 2]
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "start_execution_internal": 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The operation cannot be started by an account that uses SQL Server Authentication. Start the operation with an account that uses Integrated Authentication.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
```

Can anyone help me into it am not able to run Job as we need to set dynamic parameter value so can anyone help me into it?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: The error is *very* clear; you **cannot** start a package with SQL Authentication. You need to use a Windows Authenticated account. `EXECUTE AS` does not get around that as you are only impersonating them, you aren't actually *authenticated* as them, and so the SSIS process cannot be started as the `LOGIN` you're impersonating.

Comment: i know it but I am not able to USED Windows Authentication as my entire API is run in SQL Authentication so please suggest me to change in Stored Procedure so i can run SSIS using Windows Authenticated

Comment: Then you need to look at a different solution. Perhaps, for example, `INSERT` details of the package and parameters that need to be run in a table, and then have an agent task (which is using AD) loop through the unprocessed tasks.

Comment: i am not looking for this solution for now as i have WEB_API to run it so it is not work for me

Comment: Then you need to update your API to use Windows Authentication.